# whats wrong with this mysql insert query?

Tags: mysql, union, insert-update

```
insert into tblcustomermachine
(
 select * from
 ((select vch_CustomerID  from tblcustomer where tblcustomer.vch_CustomerID='Cust00001' )
 union all
 (select Rate  from tblmachine))  as t );
```

that table contains 18 cols and this resultset also contains 18 rows yet it shows " Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" . why?

Comment: resultset also contains 18 rows. It must contain 18 columns in result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your table `tblcustomermachine` has more then the 1 column.

Like Simone answered, update your insert to `INSERT INTO tblcustomermachine(col_1) SELECT ...`

You may skip the column names during `INSERT`, however the `SELECT` needs to return the same amount of columns that the table holds.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have to declare field name:

```
insert into tblcustomermachine (col_1, col_2, col_3, ... col_18) (
   select t.field1, t.field2, t.field3, ... t.field18 from (
      (select vch_CustomerID from tblcustomer where tblcustomer.vch_CustomerID='Cust00001') 
       union all (select Rate from tblmachine))
   as t
   );
```